# Android Display Invisible View in Table row

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Hey in my code I have a table which is being populated dynamically by a method that I call. The table row when added has an invisible view which I would like to display for each particular row when its clicked and all the others to remain hidden here is my code

```
public void createTable(String itemName,String itemQuantity,String itemPrice,String itemAmount){
    final TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    tr1.setId(id);
    tr1.setClickable(true);

    tr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0;i<lytTableData.getChildCount();i++){
        tr1.getChildAt(4).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        tr1.getChildAt(4).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    });

    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    EditText textViewItemQuantity;
    TextView textViewItemName,textViewItemPrice,textViewItemAmount;

    textViewItemName= new TextView(this);textViewItemQuantity= new EditText(this);textViewItemPrice= new TextView(this);textViewItemAmount= new TextView(this);
    iv2 = new ImageView(this);
    textViewItemName.setWidth(500);textViewItemQuantity.setWidth(100);textViewItemPrice.setWidth(100);textViewItemAmount.setWidth(100);
    textViewItemName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 6f));
    textViewItemQuantity.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemPrice.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemName.setText(itemName);textViewItemQuantity.setText(itemQuantity);textViewItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);textViewItemAmount.setText(itemAmount);  
    textViewItemQuantity.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large); textViewItemPrice.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    textViewItemName.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large); textViewItemAmount.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    textViewItemName.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemQuantity.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemPrice.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemAmount.setTextColor(0xFF121212);
    textViewItemName.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemQuantity.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemPrice.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemAmount.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);
    textViewItemQuantity.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
    iv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textViewItemQuantity.setOnClickListener(editTextRows);
    tr1.addView(textViewItemName);tr1.addView(textViewItemQuantity);tr1.addView(textViewItemPrice);tr1.addView(textViewItemAmount);tr1.addView(iv2);
    lytTableData.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Double intItemAmount = Double.parseDouble(itemAmount);
    intTotalAmount = intTotalAmount + intItemAmount;
    intTotalAmount2 = intTotalAmount2 + intItemAmount;
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(intTotalAmount));
    //txtDiscount.setText("0");
    txtAmount.setText(String.valueOf(intTotalAmount));
    id = id + 1;
        System.out.println(tr1.getId());
}
```

using this method I'm able to create a new row every time I call it
what could I be missing to make it work just to be clear what is not working is the displaying of the Invisible View it displays but not the way i want it. I want it to display on the row clicked and all the rest to remain invisible and when another row is clicked it is displayed and all the rest remain invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I was finally able to figure it out thanks to all who tried and here is the answer

```
public void createTable(String itemName,String itemQuantity,String itemPrice,String itemAmount){
    final TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    tr1.setId(id);
    tr1.setClickable(true);

    tr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        TableRow vi = (TableRow) lytTableData.getChildAt(lytTableData.indexOfChild(tr1));
        for(int i = 0;i<lytTableData.getChildCount();i++){
            TableRow vi2 = (TableRow) lytTableData.getChildAt(i);
            vi2.getChildAt(4).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }       
        vi.getChildAt(4).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    });

    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView textViewItemName,textViewItemPrice;

    textViewItemName= new TextView(this);textViewItemQuantity= new EditText(this);textViewItemPrice= new TextView(this);textViewItemAmount= new TextView(this);
    iv2 = new ImageView(this);
    textViewItemName.setWidth(500);textViewItemQuantity.setWidth(100);textViewItemPrice.setWidth(100);textViewItemAmount.setWidth(100);
    textViewItemName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 6f));
    textViewItemQuantity.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemPrice.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    textViewItemName.setText(itemName);textViewItemQuantity.setText(itemQuantity);textViewItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);textViewItemAmount.setText(itemAmount);  
    textViewItemQuantity.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large); textViewItemPrice.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    textViewItemQuantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    textViewItemName.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large); textViewItemAmount.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
    textViewItemName.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemQuantity.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemPrice.setTextColor(0xFF121212);textViewItemAmount.setTextColor(0xFF121212);
    textViewItemName.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemQuantity.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemPrice.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);textViewItemAmount.setPadding(0, 15, 5, 0);
    textViewItemQuantity.setBackgroundColor(0x0000000000);
    iv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams((int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            lytTableData.removeView(tr1);
        }

    });
    tr1.addView(textViewItemName);tr1.addView(textViewItemQuantity);tr1.addView(textViewItemPrice);tr1.addView(textViewItemAmount);tr1.addView(iv2);
    lytTableData.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Double intItemAmount = Double.parseDouble(itemAmount);
    intTotalAmount = intTotalAmount + intItemAmount;
    //intTotalAmount2 = intTotalAmount2 + intItemAmount;
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(intTotalAmount));
    //txtDiscount.setText("0");
    txtAmount.setText(String.valueOf(intTotalAmount));
    id = id + 1;
        System.out.println(tr1.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining your dynamic layout (which you want to be displayed on click) in your list view's row layout file, keep it invisible / gone by-default and mark it as visible for clicked row on onItemClickListener event of list view.
Hope this help you.

If you are using base adapter then it would be better to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm so sorry I was not clear on this I'm using a Table Layout not a listview